# scalac: should -target:jam-1.7 also include -javabootclasspath <java 1.7 home>/jre/lib/rt.jar?

Tags: java, scala, cross-compiling

When compiling Java for an older JRE with -source, it is recommended to set the bootclasspath to the corresponding rt.jar:

https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/bootclasspath_older_source

The point of this is to avoid problems when using a newer JDK to compile Java code for an older JRE where the runtime library could be different. These differences can lead to nasty problems difficult to figure out as explained here:

https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/how_to_cross_compile_for

For example, if we use the current JDK8 but compile for a JRE7 platform, then we'd do something like this (on unix):

```
JAVA7_HOME=...
javac -source 1.7 -bootclasspath $JAVA7_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar ...
```

I'm wondering whether we should do the same with Scala, e.g.:

```
scalac -target:jvm-1.7 -javabootclasspath $JAVA7_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar ...
```

That is, do the concerns about differences in the JRE runtime library for compiling java source code also apply to compiling scala source code as well?

Comment: I'd say yes, but you'd likely have to list the scala libraries too if you override the boot classpath.

Comment: scalac has two separate options: -bootclasspath and -javabootclasspath. My understanding is that the latter is unrelated to the scala libraries.